# Print range using for-loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I need to print a range of numbers in a range using a function and a for-loop.
Again I'm stuck on the return value. I believe my code is sufficient for the task but if you have a better idea I'm all ears.

```
function printRange(rangeStart, rangeStop) {    
    var text = "";
        for (var i = rangeStart; i < rangeStop; i++) {
            text += i + ',';
        }
    return text;
    var result = text;
}

printRange(20, 47);
```

The 'result' is ought to print the numbers 20,21,22...,46,47 but of course it doesn't...
Any help is appreciated.
Regards, Thomas

Comment: `return` exits the function, the line below doesn't get reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you need to fix - your code doesn't print `rangeStop`, but it does include a trailing comma.

You can fix the former by changing your loop end condition to use `<=`, and [`String.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) can do the latter.

```js
function printRange(rangeStart, rangeStop) {
  var text = "";
  for (var i = rangeStart; i <= rangeStop; i++) {
    text += i + ',';
  }

  return text.slice(0, -1);
}

document.write(printRange(20, 47));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function printAllNum(rangeStart, rangeEnd){
  for(let i = rangeStart; i <= rangeEnd; i++) {
  document.write(i + " ")}
}
printAllNum(1,20);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).